# How to turn off index merge, MySQL

Tags: mysql

I encounter a dead lock problem when updating a separate records in two transactions.

According to our diagnose, it should be caused by index merge.

And 
    select @@optimizer_switch;

```
index_merge=on,index_merge_union=on,index_merge_sort_union=on,index_merge_intersection=on....
```

indeed shows the index merge is on . So we hope to turn off it. But I cannot find the command, can anyone give me an answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is given in the [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/switchable-optimizations.html):

> To change the value of optimizer_switch, assign a value consisting of
>   a comma-separated list of one or more commands:

```
SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] optimizer_switch='command[,command]...';
```

Try the following to disable it Globally:

```
SET GLOBAL optimizer_switch='index_merge=off,index_merge_union=off,index_merge_sort_union=off,index_merge_intersection=off';
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I never used it but I found this in the reference manual, maybe can help you:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/switchable-optimizations.html

> SET [GLOBAL|SESSION] optimizer_switch='command[,command]...';
>   Each command value should have one of the forms shown in the following table.
>
> Command Syntax Meaning
>
> default    Reset every optimization to its default value
>
> opt_name=default   Set the named optimization to its default value
>
> opt_name=off   Disable the named optimization
>
> opt_name=on    Enable the named optimization